# Windows: Unable to find SAPI error on google

Tags: c++, windows, sapi, error-code

I am using SAPI to make a voice speak text.
The error code returned is

```
-2147024888

The method "Speak" for 'ISpeechVoice' failed
```

However I was unable to find this error code on Google.
I am not sure why.
Does anybody have any ideas? I expected Microsoft to list all possible error codes for SAPI. 
On the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx this error code is not there.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAPI error code listings are for the error codes specific to SAPI.  Other errors could be returned.

`-2147024888` is equivalent to `0x80070008`, which is a Win32 HRESULT (E_OUTOFMEMORY); the call is failing because something (either inside the TTS engine or in SAPI) is not able to allocate enough memory.